# ASP.NET : Logic for Image Resizing proportionaly

Tags: c#, logic

I have a C# function to REsize images.The parameters of the funciton would be  orginal image path,new image path(path after saving the resizing of image).
Now i want to build a logic for the below requirement.

1 . If the orginal file's width is greater than 480 or lessthan 450 ,then i want to set the width of output image as 450px.and the height has to be proportional of the width.

2. If the width of the orginal file  is > its height, then add white space to the top and to bottom (to the height) so that the new height will be 650.

I m using the follwing code to resize image

```
try
    {
        Size oldSize=new Size();
        Bitmap oldbmp1 = (Bitmap) Bitmap.FromFile(originalpath);
        oldSize.Width=oldbmp1.Width;
        oldSize.Height=oldbmp1.Height;

        Size newSize=new Size()

        using (Bitmap newbmp = new Bitmap(newsize.Width, newsize.Height), oldbmp = Bitmap.FromFile(originalpath) as Bitmap)
        {
            Graphics newgraphics = Graphics.FromImage(newbmp);
            newgraphics.InterpolationMode =  System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
           // newsize = GetNewImageSize(oldSize); // here i want the new Size
            newgraphics.Clear(Color.FromArgb(-1));
            newgraphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, 0, 0, newsize.Width, newsize.Height);

            newgraphics.DrawImage(oldbmp, 0, 0, newsize.Width, newsize.Height);

                try
                {
                   // newgraphics.Save();

                    ImageCodecInfo[] Info = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders();
                    EncoderParameters Params = new EncoderParameters(1);
                    Params.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality, 100L);
                    newbmp.Save(newpath, Info[1], Params);
                }
                catch (Exception ex1)
                {
                    throw ex1;
                }
                finally
                {
                    newbmp.Dispose();
                    oldbmp.Dispose();
                    oldbmp1.Dispose();
                }

        }
    }
    catch (Exception ee)
    {
        throw ee;
    }
```

Can any one advice what else i have to add on this ?

## EDIT  (Since comment field will not allow me to have more characters)

I tried this

```
float ratio = oldImg.Width / oldImg.Height;
SizeF newSize = new SizeF(desiredWidth, desiredWidth * ratio);
```

But it will not worked as i wish
 Ex : My orginal image had width 450 and height 1094.
 So ratio=450/1094  which is 0.4113;
 Desired height=desired width * ratio ie ; 450*0.4113 which is 185 .1

How its proportional . I think some thing has to be corrected.Any more thoughts ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

What you need is a simple ratio between the width and height of the image. Basic arithmetics.

```
float ratio = oldImg.Width / oldImg.Height;
SizeF newSize = new SizeF(desiredWidth, desiredWidth / ratio);
```

With this the new size will be proportional to the old size.

**Edited to correct a type and to clarify**

I think there's a lacking of mathematics, so here it goes:

Let's say we have an image **100 (w) x 200 (h)**, with an ratio (w/h) of **0.5**, and want to resize it to an width of **400**. We simply divide the desired width by the ratio, thus giving us **800**, the correct answer.

Now, if we wanted to resize the same image to an width of **50**, dividing it by the ratio, would give us an height of **100**.

Because of a typo on my previous version of the answer I used an `*` instead of an `/`, and that made my answer wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you need to flip the fraction.  Divide by your ratio instead of multiply.  That will give you the original 1094.